# Blueprint CSS compress.rb errors

Tags: ruby, compression, blueprint-css

I'm trying to use the Ruby compressor for custom layout and I was just using the examples bundled with Blueprint. I installed both Bundler and ChunkyPNG, this is what I've got:

```
D:\bp\lib>ruby compress.rb -p project1
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.14/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:87:in `block in materialize': Could not find ffi-1.0.8 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)
from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.14/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:81:in `map!'
from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.14/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:81:in `materialize'
from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.14/lib/bundler/definition.rb:90:in `specs'
from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.14/lib/bundler/definition.rb:135:in `specs_for'
from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.14/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:11:in `setup'
from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.14/lib/bundler.rb:115:in `setup'
from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.14/lib/bundler.rb:120:in `require'
from D:/bp/lib/blueprint/blueprint.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
from compress.rb:2:in `<main>'
```

I can't understand a single line of what is written there, any chance to make it work, please?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last Joshua Clayton (Blueprint css author) helped me with that: http://groups.google.com/group/blueprintcss/browse_thread/thread/c19b41c2f8ea06fc/7cc3f1a0f2031295?show_docid=7cc3f1a0f2031295
The solution was to use "bundle install --without test": pretty tricky...

Answer (score 0):

ffi gem is not installed. Try again after this command `bundle install`.

Comment: Many thanks, I tried that command and now it works, but it stops with errors while installing capybara-webkit: Installing capybara-webkit (0.3.0) with native extensions C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/si
te_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/installer.rb:529:in `rescue in block in build_extensions': ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension. (Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError)
        C:/Ruby192/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
Gem files will remain installed in C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/capybara-webkit-0.3.0 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/capybara-webkit-0.3.0/./gem_make.out